# onClick event in separate document

Tags: javascript, document

I've done a webpage and I would like to keep all my onClick events in a seperate JS document, as I do with the rest of the Javascripts I'm using.

The snippets I'm using atm in the HTML I would like to change at the moment is these:

```
<a href="http://www.commercial.com" onclick="confirmLeave()" target="_blank">
```

and

```
<IMG SRC="picture_small.jpg" alt="Description" onClick="view(this);">
```

And the connected Javascript code that I keep in a seperate document is this:

```
function confirmLeave() {
    if (confirm("Do you want to leave this page?")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (window.event) {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And

```
function view(img) {
    imgsrc = img.src.split("_")[0] + "_big.jpg";
    viewwin = window.open(imgsrc, 'viewwin', "width=790,height=444,location=0");
    viewwin.focus();
}
```

The first is to ask if the visitors want to leave my page when they click on a link leading to an external site; the other one is to show a bigger version of the picture they clicked on.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `<script src="./yourdoc.js" />` That work?

Comment: I already have a separate document for it, but I would like to have my onClick events in it as well.

Comment: You can put the functions in a separate file too. Just link it the same way. It has to have the onclick="function()" in HTML to work at all.

Comment: So there isn't any way to keep event handlers in the separate document? I got the function there already

Comment: Ok. I understood. =) Yes U can do it. But these functions should be enhanced and check whether clicked element should be oncliked or not and proper function should run for 'a' and 'img'. And onclick event should be attached to 'body' or any other container, where your elements are. And so on.

Comment: And there is no way you can show how this is done? :)

Comment: @Benji: how it done exactly - no. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link to an external javascript file like this.

`<script src="http://yoururl.com/myjs.js"></script>`